# Highlight "find all in current document" search results in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

If you use the option to "find all in current document" Notepad++ opens a window at the bottom of the screen with all the search results listed by line. However, the actual searched characters are not highlighted in this list, unlike in the main file window. Is there any setting/plugin that can change this behavior?

Comment: They are for me ...

Comment: @DavidPostill That is great, any chance you might know why they aren't for me?

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

#### The actual searched characters are not highlighted in this list

You need to change the Search result style:

1. Menu > Settings > Style Configurator
2. Scroll to the bottom of the Language list and select "Search Result"
3. Select "Hit Word" in the Style list
4. Choose your Foreground and Background Colors
5. Press "Save & Close"

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have it set the same way, but there is still no highlighting. Tried changing colors, still nothing. Although this does look to be the correct place.

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work for you. The colors change on the fly for me if I change them.